# Aurora MySQL reader performance degrades over time

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-administration, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora MySQL cluster and when running queries against the reader I see a degradation in performance over time.  A reboot of the reader results in query performance that matches the writer.  But after going a week without a reboot queries take 25x as long to run.

The replication lag for the reader instance is 20ms and none of the monitoring metrics are showing issues.  The highest I have seen the CPU is 40%. I tried a suggestion to set block_nested_loop to off but that had no effect.

The reader does not get much activity so load should not be an issue.  We do need to run a complex query against it that returns a lot of data which is used for analytics.  I have found that queries that return a small number of records that are retrieved by an index do NOT have the performance problem.  But a similar query that returns the same small number of records and requires a table scan does have the performance problem.

The rate of degradation seems consistent, so it seems like a resource issue related to replication, but I have not had any luck finding anything online documenting the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:** Additional details

### Query execution plans

```sql
-- Fast query
explain select cpv.SHORT_TEXT_VALUE, c.UIDPK, c.GUID, c.SHARED_ID, cpv.* 
from TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE cpv 
inner join TCUSTOMER c on cpv.CUSTOMER_UID = c.UIDPK
where LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = 'CP_EMAIL' and cpv.SHORT_TEXT_VALUE = 'some-email@gmail.com';
```

[image]

```sql
-- Slow query, using function to prevent use of index for email match
explain select cpv.SHORT_TEXT_VALUE, c.UIDPK, c.GUID, c.SHARED_ID, cpv.* 
from TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE cpv 
inner join TCUSTOMER c on cpv.CUSTOMER_UID = c.UIDPK
where LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = 'CP_EMAIL' and LOWER(cpv.SHORT_TEXT_VALUE) = 'some-email@gmail.com';
```

[image]

### Table definitions

```sql
CREATE TABLE `TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE` (
  `UIDPK` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTE_UID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTE_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SHORT_TEXT_VALUE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LONG_TEXT_VALUE` mediumtext,
  `INTEGER_VALUE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DECIMAL_VALUE` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BOOLEAN_VALUE` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `DATE_VALUE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_UID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UIDPK`),
  KEY `I_CPV_ATTR_UID` (`ATTRIBUTE_UID`),
  KEY `I_CPV_CUID_ATTKEY` (`CUSTOMER_UID`,`LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY`),
  KEY `I_CPV_STV_ATTVALUE` (`SHORT_TEXT_VALUE`),
  KEY `I_CPV_ATTKEY_SHORTTEXT` (`LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY`,`SHORT_TEXT_VALUE`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PROFILE_CUSTOMER` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_UID`) REFERENCES `TCUSTOMER` (`UIDPK`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ATTRIBUTE_UID`) REFERENCES `TATTRIBUTE` (`UIDPK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='values associated with customer profiles.'

CREATE TABLE `TCUSTOMER` (
  `UIDPK` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PREF_BILL_ADDRESS_UID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREF_SHIP_ADDRESS_UID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LAST_EDIT_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `GUID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHENTICATION_UID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STORECODE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_FIRST_TIME_BUYER` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `CUSTOMER_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `SHARED_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PARENT_CUSTOMER_GUID` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DTYPE` varchar(40) DEFAULT 'ExtCustomerImpl',
  `LAST_SESSION_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UIDPK`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TCUSTOMER_UNIQUE` (`GUID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TCUSTOMER_SHARED_ID_TYPE_UNIQ` (`SHARED_ID`,`CUSTOMER_TYPE`),
  UNIQUE KEY `I_CUST_AUTH_UID` (`AUTHENTICATION_UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SHARED_ID` (`SHARED_ID`,`STORECODE`),
  KEY `I_CUST_CR_DATE` (`CREATION_DATE`),
  KEY `I_CUST_STORE_CODE` (`STORECODE`),
  KEY `I_TYPE_LAST_EDIT` (`CUSTOMER_TYPE`,`LAST_EDIT_DATE`),
  KEY `I_CUSTOMER_SHAREDID` (`SHARED_ID`),
  KEY `I_CUSTOMER_PARENT` (`PARENT_CUSTOMER_GUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_STORECODE_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`STORECODE`) REFERENCES `TSTORE` (`STORECODE`),
  CONSTRAINT `TCUSTOMER_PARENT_GUID_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_CUSTOMER_GUID`) REFERENCES `TCUSTOMER` (`GUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='customer account information.'
```

### Indexes

[image: TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE Indexes]

[image: TCUSTOMER Indexes]

Comment: In the absence of any specific code (and even if there was code) this looks like it's more appropriate for [dba.se] or possibly even [sf]

Comment: Post A) EXPLAIN SELECT ....... TEXT results of your ..... query that returns the same small number of records and requires a table scan does have the performance problem.  Post B) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each query used and POST C) each SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks for your response. To clarify, the issue I am trying to resolve is the degradation in performance on the reader.  The performance of the query is NOT degrading over time on the writer so why is the reader performance degrading.  Also the complex query that we are running for analytics is expected to do table scans given the number of joins and the amount of data being returned.  So I don't think index tuning will solve the overall problem.

Comment: For someone to assist, please post data AT dba.stackoverflow.com ONLY from your reader instance, requested about an hour ago.  We know it takes time to answer what might seem to be silly requests.

Comment: Is the number of _writes_ increasing over time?  What performance metric is degrading over time?  Is it just that one complex Select?  Is it touching more rows than it used to? 
 Let's see the query.  I'll chime in with Wilson by saying that the information may point in an unexpected direction.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated the post with the requested details.  Let me know if there are additional details that would be helpful.

Comment: @RickJames the writes performed on the writer are not increasing over time.  This system is not in production yet so load is not significant.  I don't see any performance metrics that show degradation on the reader, except for the time for the queries to complete.  The number of records returned by the query is not changing significantly it at all.  I am not sure if the total records in the tables being queried has increased significantly (I don't think so), but the reboot restores the query to the expected level of performance so I don't believe total record count is a factor in the slowness.

Comment: @redfish819 Since your initial concern was reader time after reboot is 25x faster than reader time a week later, consider posting these 4 pieces of information.  Soon after reboot, A) EXPLAIN SELECT xxxxx;SHOW WARNINGS;  so we can see what the optimizer did with your query before running the request. B) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; you may have to use pastebin.com to share with us if it is extensive.  Provide the pastebin.com links.  A WEEK LATER, C) EXPLAIN SELECT xxxxx;SHOW WARNINGS; to compare optimizer differences, if any a week later and D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; Thanks

Comment: Also, post the complete SOURCE QUERY you are using after reboot and a week later, please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't explain the shift in performance unless the Optimizer is randomly shifting between different query plans.

I do see that you are using the notorious Entity-Attribute-Value schema design.  And doing it in a rather bulky and complex way -- with multiple columns for different datatypes.

I do see a few things that can probably help performance in general as the dataset grows.  (I assume it will grow.)

The primary key, `UIDPK` of the attribute table `TCUSTOMERPROFILEVALUE` probably has no use.  This will probably be better: `PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_UID, ATTRIBUTE_UID)`.  Or maybe that should be `LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY`???  Why are there two columns for the attribute?

When changing the PK, this KEY `I_CPV_ATTKEY_SHORTTEXT` (`LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY`,`SHORT_TEXT_VALUE`) would implicitly have `CUSTOMER_UID` added on the end, thereby benefiting your `JOIN`.

`BIGINT` is usually overkill; consider using a smaller datatype.

Do you have another attribute table - `TATTRIBUTE`?

Having 5 `UNIQUE` keys for a table slows down inserts.  Perhaps you can have fewer?

`INDEX(SHARED_ID)` is redundant since there are other keys starting with that column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions on how to improve the database design.  Most of what is here is from a system that we are customizing, though some indexes may have been changed/added. At this point our focus is on fixing the problem with degrading performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried removing the LOWER(xxxx) from the SLOW QUERY?

If this corrects the problem, and  your results are the same, you were just wasting time with the LOWER(xxx) manipulation.

Comment: I am using the LOWER function to prevent the index from being used to match on email.  I am doing this to see the performance when many table pages have to be read to resolve the query.  The performance of the slow query after a restart is not the concern, it is the fact that it's performance degrades over time.

Comment: Monitor SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%dirty%'; hourly to get a sense of dirty pages that could be causing slowdown over time.  In your summary, document the date and time of the count of DIRTY PAGES.   Consider eliminating the LOWER(function) altogether to conserve cpu cycles and table scan.

Comment: @redfish819 Do you have any DIRTY PAGES counts monitored hourly you can share with us?